# Can check my arithmetic/work on this arc length problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the length of the curve $y^2 = x^3$ from (0,0) to $(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8})$.

I know that the arc length formula for rectangular problems is:

$$ \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + (\frac{dy}{dx})^2} $$

So, to get a, I subtract $\frac{1}{4}$ from 0. To get b, I subtract $\frac{1}{8}$ from 0.

So now I have my bounds. Now I need take the derivative of my function.

$$ y = x^\frac{3}{2} $$

Derivative:

$$ y = \frac{3}{2} x^\frac{1}{2} $$

Square it:

$$ y = \frac{9}{4}x $$

Plug it into my original equation:

$$ \int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{1 + \frac{9}{4}} x $$

This leaves me with

$$ \int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{8} 1 + \frac{3}{2}x $$

Swap a and b around, add negative sign and set up the equation:

$$ - [ 1 + \frac{3}{8} ] - [1 + \frac{3}{16} ] $$

Finals result:

$$ -\frac{11}{8} - \frac{19}{16}  ==  -\frac{30}{16} == -\frac{15}{8} $$

Comment: For starters, the $x$ must be in the square root.  Second, $\sqrt{a+b}\neq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$.  To evaluate
$$\int_{1/4}^{1/3}\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{4}x}\,dx$$
consider making the substitution $u=1+\frac{9}{4}x$.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherToni for letting me know that I can't split the values under the square root. On a side note, your upper bound seems to be a typo.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  It looked like a 3 instead of an 8 to me on my screen...my apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.

First, the [arc length formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) is $\displaystyle s = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2} dx$, where $a$ is the $x$ value you start with, $b$ is the $x$ value you end with.

In this case, $y^2 = x^3$. This gives $y = x^{\frac{3}{2}}$, and $y' = \frac{3}{2} x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Square that, and you get $(y')^2 = \frac{9}{4} x$. The starting point is $a = 0$, and the ending point is $b = \frac{1}{4}$.

Using these, we get $\displaystyle s = \int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{9}{4}x\right)} dx$, which, according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1%2B9%2F4%2ax%5D%2Cx%2C0%2C1%2F4%5D) turns out to be $\displaystyle \frac{61}{216}$.

Comment: If I don't use Wolfram I could just u-sub everything under the square root and integrate the u, correct? Thanks for spotting my mistakes! I tend to make them often unfortunately. I can't believe that I missed the a and b values!

Comment: I think a u-sub would be a good way to work this problem through if you're not using Wolfram Alpha. Or maybe an [integral table](http://integral-table.com/downloads/integral-table.pdf) if you're given one.